# List of all spring-boot metrics micrometer properties

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I couldn't find list of all supported spring-boot metrics micrometer properties. Can someone share good documentation link that I can refer? I am looking for enabling additional histogram metrics for WebClient integrations.